# Predefined variables in previous Azure Pipeline Build

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

How can I get the predefined variables used in a past Azure pipeline build.

When I navigate to this build I can see the logs, many information but not the actual values of the predefined variables by the time of that build.

I managed to see the queued time variables, but there is only three: `BuildConfiguration`, `BuildPlatform` and `system.debug`.

For example, how could I check what was the `Build.DefinitionName` or `Build.BuildNumber` used in that particular build?

Comment: I think you should be able to see them if you add variable `system.debug=true` to your pipeline.

Comment: @CarlosParra, I set this variable to true, but I still cannot find all the variables in the build results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a Command Line task and just put one command (in the "Script" field): `set`, so this task will print all the environment variables during the build and you can see them in the logs every time.

Task configuration:

[image]

Task result:

[image]