# What is the predefined build variable name for the random number in azure on on prem build agent BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY path

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have my azure pipeline setup with my on prem agent. I need to know the predefined variable to get the random number in my `**BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY**` = **C:\Users\Administrator\agent_work\78\a** (i.e.) **78** in this path.

I gave a look at [Predefined Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but could find this.

I also followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887671/10851213). But that **78** is not defined in any variable.

Please can anyone assist on how to find the variable?

Comment: I'll be checking this. Will check and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know the predefined variable to get the random number.

The `78` is not a predefined variable, so we can't use documented predefined variable to represents it.

Also, this is **not** a random number. Every time we create a new pipeline and run the pipeline on specific agent, it will create a new `number-folder` under `agent_work` or `_work` folder.

[image]

**Some details about how the `78` comes:**

I once used the agent to run six different pipelines, so I got six folders under my `_work` folder (Same as your `agent_work` folder). If I create a new build pipeline and then run the pipeline using this agent, then I would get new folder `7`. So every `number folder` here can represent a pipeline.

And their secrets are stored in `SourceRootMapping` folder. The `Mappings.json` file under that records the last build number, it will increase every time when new folder is created. And you can find many folders named with `BuildDefinitionID`, within them you can find `SourceFolder.json` file which info about:

- The relationship between number folder and corresponding pipeline
- Agent dir, AgentArtifactstagingDir, ...
- Last run time, RepoID, OrgID, ProjectID...

> Please can anyone assist on how to find the variable?

For now the `Agent.BuildDirectory` variable is the closest to the Folder number you need. So you can add one Powershell Inline task at the start of your pipeline to get the Folder number. My PS script:

```
#Get the FolderID so that following commands in this task can use it via $FolderID.
$FolderID = Split-Path "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)" -Leaf

#Check its value.
Write-Host $FolderID

#Set it as job-scoped variable so that following ateps/tasks can use it via $(FolderID).
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FolderID]$FolderID"
```

Execute this script at the first of your pipeline, and then **following tasks** can access the custom defined variable via `$(FolderID)`. To use the FolderID in **first PS task** you should use $FolderID instead.

Comment: `$FolderID` variable needs to be added in variables section?

Comment: @fingers10 No, we don't need to change anything in variables section.

Comment: @fingers10 The `$FolderID` is a temporary variable defined by me, it is valid for the PS task lifestyle. And the `$(FolderID)` is also a variable defined by me, I pass the value of $FolderID to it, so it will work for whole job. See [set variables from scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts). The FolderID is just a random name, you can rename it if you want.

Comment: @fingers10 Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Tested and that works. Thanks for the detailed explanation and support @Lance Li-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined variable for the build directory ID. An alternative way to get this id as a variable would be to extract it from the `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` during the pipeline run.

If you are using `Linux` environment, you can do that like this:

```
export BUILD_DIRECTORY_ID=$(echo $(Agent.BuildDirectory) | sed 's|.*\/||)
```

If you are using `Windows` environment:

```
$build_id = (echo $(Agent.BuildDirectory) | %{$_ -replace "(?s)^.*\\", ""})
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_DIRECTORY_ID", $build_id, "User")
```